# Is there a way to process web payments with square without manually entering the payment information?

Tags: web, payment, credit-card, square

I'm working on building a website for a friend, and they would love to use Square for their payment processing. I'm just wondering if there is a way for me to automatically process a payment with square from the website I am building? I looked around a little, but didn't find any information about an API that I can send CC information to Square automatically and have the clients charged.

I know paypal is another very popular option, but I'm just curious if this can be done with Square?

Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 1):

I used square for several years and they did not seem eager to offer an api.  They do seem to have one now, but I don't know much about it.  Check out connect.squareup.com -- they don't actually let you process charges, though.  It meant more as a reporting and inventory tool.

The real benefit of Square is the ability to swipe wherever you are.  If you want to be able to upload transactions in bulk, you might look at authorize.net -- I know they, among others,  have that capability.

Comment: Ya, my client does both in person sales (which square does very well) and online sales. They were hoping to be able to just use square for everything.